# Is there a way to get confirmation from the scheduler that the job has been accepted?

Tags: dask-distributed

I'm using `dask.distributed.Client` to connect to a remote Dask scheduler running that manages a bunch of workers.  I am submitting my job using `client.submit` and keeping track of the returned `Future`:

```
client = Client("some-example-host:8786")
future = client.submit(job, job_args)
```

I want to be able to know if/when the job has been sent to and accepted by the scheduler.  This is so that I can add some retry logic in cases when the scheduler goes down.

Is there an easy way to get confirmation that the scheduler has received and accepted the job?

Some additional points:

- I realise that `distributed.client.Future` has a `status` property, but I'm hesitant to use it as it was not documented in the API.
- I have tried using `dask.callbacks.Callback` but with no success.  Any assistance with using callbacks with `distributed.Client` would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I could also have the job post back a notification when it starts, but I would like to leave this approach as a last resort if the Client does not support this.